# Which is the best multitrack recording software?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, music

What is the best multi-track recording software for Ubuntu? I know Ardour is one of them but I heard it is a bit complicated to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the following applications:

- [Jokosher](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jokosher/)
- [Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/audacity/)
- [Traverso](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/traverso/)

Here is the what their summaries says on the USC.

***Jokosher:***

> Jokosher is a simple and powerful multi-track studio. Jokosher
>   provides a complete application for recording, editing, mixing and
>   exporting audio, and has been specifically designed with usability in
>   mind. The developers behind Jokosher have re-thought audio production
>   at every level, and created something devilishly simple to use.
>
> Jokosher offers a strong feature set:
>
> - Easy to use interface, designed from the ground up. Jokosher uses    concepts and language familiar to musicians, and is a breeze to use.
> - Simple editing with splitting, trimming and moving tools.
> - Multi-track volume mixing with VU sliders.
> - Import audio (Ogg Vorbis, MP3, FLAC, WAV and anything else supported    by GStreamer) into your projects.
> - A range of instruments can be added to a project, and instruments can    be renamed.
> - Instruments can also be muted and soloed easily.
> - Export to MP3, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, WAV and anything else GStreamer    supports.

***Audacity:***

> Audacity is a multi-track audio editor for Linux/Unix, MacOS and
>   Windows.  It is designed for easy recording, playing and editing of
>   digital audio.  Audacity features digital effects and spectrum
>   analysis tools.  Editing is very fast and provides unlimited
>   undo/redo.
>
> Supported file formats include Ogg Vorbis, MP2, MP3, WAV, AIFF, and
>   AU.

***Traverso:***

> This is a free, cross platform multitrack audio recording and editing
>   suite, with an innovative and easy to master user interface. It is
>   suited for both the professional and home user, who needs a robust and
>   solid DAW.

Also you could search for more applications from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Bad links that redirect to a bad package repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user to audio editing and recording, recording my own guitar song. Tried a few apps so far, here's my opinions about them each.

- Audacity seems confusing for a newbie me. Besides, it sticks out like
  a sore thumb in GTK apps. Hard to config too.
- I love the simplicity of Jokersher, but it does not work. Too bad,
  the UI is so straightforward.

Eventually, [Ocenaudio](http://www.ocenaudio.com.br/features) does the job for me. Integrates fine into Unity, even the Global Menu works.

[image: http://www.ocenaudio.com.br/imgs/screenshot_multiselecao.png]

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu Studio, which comes pre-compiled with Ardour, Audacity and a ton of other useful software for media production. I personally like Rosegarden and Ardour over Audacity, but use all 3 for different things. Here is some reading material :)

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardour_%28software%29
- http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_%28audio_editor%29
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_audio_software

all should be available through software center/synaptic/repos.

Some info on a full multimedia distro like Ubuntu Studio...

- http://ubuntustudio.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Studio